# sum cell based on lower case (Case sensitive) letter?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a program that should sum only the row with a lower case c. The code I have now, sums all rows beginning with c, regardless if upper or lower case. How I can I write it so that it is case sensitive?
Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub summ()
Dim iArea As Long

With Worksheets("K00304.RPT")
    With .Range("A14", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = "ZERO"
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="ZERO*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 
1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '.Offset(-1)
            For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
                With .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Offset(1), .Areas(iArea + 
1).Offset(-1))
                    Worksheets("Total").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"AF").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Cells, "c*", 
.Offset(, 7))
                End With
            Next
        End With
        .Cells(2, 1).ClearContents
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the characters with `StrConv()`:

```
Sub t()
Dim cel As Range
Set cel = Range("A1")
If StrConv(Left(cel, 1), vbProperCase) = Left(cel, 1) And Left(cel, 1) = "C" Then
    'There's a match, the left letter is capitalized.
    Debug.Print "'C' is present"
End If
End Sub
```

Edit: Actually, just checking `If LEFT(cel,1) = "C" Then` seems to work too.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne! is there an easy way I can work this into my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Evaluate` function and sumproduct formula, hopefully this works.

```
Sub summ()
Dim iArea As Long

With Worksheets("K00304.RPT")
    With .Range("A14", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = "ZERO"
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="ZERO*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '.Offset(-1)
            For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
                With .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Offset(1), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1))

                    Dim criteria_range As String
                    Dim sum_range As String
                    Dim criteria As String
                    Dim sum_ifs_case_sensitive As Long

                    criteria = "c"
                    criteria_range = .Cells.Address
                    sum_range = .Offset(, 7).Address
                    sum_ifs_case_sensitive = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(" & Chr(34) & criteria & Chr(34) & "," & criteria_range & ")))," & sum_range & ")")

                    Worksheets("Total").Cells(Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sum_ifs_case_sensitive

                End With
            Next
        End With
        .Cells(2, 1).ClearContents
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite, its not summing anything now - I have a feeling there is too much code after the With .Parent.Range line. I removed the Dim's to the top but the sum_ifs_case_sensitive and sum_range lines don't appear to be doing anything.